# ESXi command to get all running services on host

Tags: vmware, esxi

Could anyone please give me the command to get the list of all services running on an ESXi host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESXCLI can be used for this, example:

```
esxcli system process list
```

Alternatively, there's also this: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1010993

Answer (score 0):

If `chkconfig` is still available (it seems on ESXi v8), you can type this command :

```bash
$ chkconfig --list | grep -w on | sort
DCUI                    on
ESXShell                on
apiForwarder            on
cdp                     on
clusterAgent            on
dcbd                    on
dellism                 on
drivervm-init           on
envoy                   on
esxTokenCPS             on
........................on
```